# How to receive output of Tortoise?

Tags: svn, redirect, tortoisesvn, updates, output

I use bat file that contains:

```
call TortoiseProc.exe /command:update /path:%updatepath% /closeonend:2  >test.txt
```

but test.txt is empty. How I can receive result of update? e.g. files that were updated,...
Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

TortoiseProc only has a return value (indicating success or failure). It is an UI client and does not use the console and does not write to it. You can not get other information from it other than the mentioned success/failure return code.

If you want to automate svn command, use the Subversion command line client instead (svn.exe).

Answer (score 1):

Does TortoiseProc.exe output something on the standard channels? I.e. do you see something on the command line when executing this command?

If yes, maybe TortoiseProc is outputting to a different channel than stdout. You can also store the other channels' output into files. See [Microsoft resource](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/redirection.mspx?mfr=true) on redirection operators. This is for Windows XP, but I don't think it has been changed in newer versions of Windows.